# Updating second Table View with respect to selection made on first

Tags: xcode, uitableview

I am looking to create a basic program for the ios that uses array of data and 2 UITableViews in one single view. I want the second UITableView to be populated by an array which is based on the selection made in first Table. I have an array of arrays for the second table. When I click on first cell of table1 then desired data is shown in table2. But when I click second cell of table1 i get error. "Index 1 beyond bounds"

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
 [super viewWillAppear:animated];
 NSString *jsonString = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http:/url.com/technology"] encoding:NSStringEncodingConversionAllowLossy error:nil];
NSString *jsonString1 = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL  URLWithString:@"http://url.com/experience1"] encoding:NSStringEncodingConversionAllowLossy error:nil];
NSString *jsonString2 = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http:url.com/experirnce2"] encoding:NSStringEncodingConversionAllowLossy error:nil];

SBJSON *parser = [[SBJSON alloc]init];
SBJSON *parser1 = [[SBJSON alloc]init];
SBJSON *parser2 = [[SBJSON alloc]init];

 NSDictionary *results = [parser objectWithString:jsonString error:nil];
[parser release], parser = nil;
    NSDictionary *results1 = [parser1 objectWithString:jsonString1 error:nil];
    NSDictionary *results2 = [parser2 objectWithString:jsonString2 error:nil];
[parser release], parser = nil;
[parser1 release], parser1 = nil;
[parser2 release], parser2 = nil;

self.technologyArray = [results objectForKey:@"response"];
self.technologyData = [technologyArray valueForKey:@"technologyname"];
self.experienceArray1 = [results1 objectForKey:@"response"];
self.experienceData1 = [experienceArray1 valueForKey:@"experiencename"];
self.experienceArray2 = [results2 objectForKey:@"response"];
self.experienceData2 = [experienceArray2 valueForKey:@"experiencename"];
experience = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:experienceData1, experienceData2, nil];


}

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
if (tableView == technologyTable)
return [technologyData count];

else {
return [experience count];
}

 }



 -(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";


UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
// Change UITableViewCellStyle
cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] 
     initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle 
     reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
 }

if (tableView == technologyTable)
{

cell.textLabel.text=[technologyData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

} 

if (tableView == experienceTable)
{
 cell.textLabel.text = [[experience  objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
[experienceTable reloadData];

}
return cell ;

}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
 if (tableView == technologyTable)
{

experienceTable = [[experience objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];


 selectTechnology.text = [technologyData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

 self.technologyList.hidden = YES;

}
 if(tableView == experienceTable)
 {
 self.experienceList.hidden = YES;
 selectExperience.text = [[experience objectAtIndex:1] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
 }
 [experience release ];

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use 2 different delegates and data sources for the 2 tables. Upon selection in the first table, its delegate would send a notification which the 2nd table's delegate would be listening for. When the 2nd table's delegate got the notification, it would set itself to display the appropriate data (either experience array and data 1 or 2), and call `[table2 reloadData]`.

Comment: can you please explain me with code. I have tried it but I get the same error again... Index 1 beyond bounds. Here experience is an array of two arrays.

Answer (score 0):

In `cellForRowAtIndexPath` you need to determine what row is selected in the first tableview (you can save the selection in an ivar) and then display the value from the appropriate array in the second tableview.
You'll need to call [experienceTable reloadData] after the user selects a value from the first table.

Something like this:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath
{
    if (tableView == technologyTable)
    {
        selectedTechnology = indexPath.row;
        [experienceTable reloadData];
    }
}
```

and then:

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    ...


    if (tableView == experienceTable)
    {
        cell.textLabel.text = experience[selectedTechnology][indexPath.row];
    }
}
```

Comment: i tried it. But whenever I put reload data in didSelectRowAtIndexPath I get SIGABRT error.

Comment: My guess is that the SIGABRT you receive is due to an infinite loop. Currently you use `reloadData` in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, which will cause it to run indefinitely. Remove it from there and try my approach, things should work out.